# Open Cart Sitemap Couldn't Fetch in Google Webmaster

Tags: opencart, google-search-console, opencart-module

I took the enabled Google Sitemap code from Opencart and installed it in my Google Search Console. It tells me "couldn't fetch." When I do a google search for it, it gives me a 500 code error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you used something like this `/index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap` or something like this `sitemap.xml`?

Comment: yes! I Submit "/index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap" but google couldn't fetch

Comment: How many products does your e-Shop has? If you open a browser and load `www.example.com/index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap` do you see any results?

Comment: @kanenas almost 6000+ products my e-shop have

Comment: If you are in a shared hosted environment I guess you are running out if resources. Check your **error_log**.